# ArrayList.contains() is not registering correctly for some values

Tags: java, arraylist

Essentially, I have a program that takes a string and finds all of the unique permutations of this string. In order to check for duplicates, I added the permutations to an arraylist as they were evaluated, then checked each permutation with arraylist.contains(). For some reason, it has only worked for some values, but has completely ignored some of the duplicates. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test
{
    private static int i;
    private static ArrayList<String> array;
    private static String temp;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        array = new ArrayList<String>();
        Permutation generator = new Permutation("tweet");
        while(generator.hasMorePermutations())
        {
            temp = generator.nextPermutation();
            if(array.contains(temp))
            {

            }
            else
            {
            array.add(generator.nextPermutation());
            System.out.println(generator.nextPermutation());
            i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This class calls methods from another class which creates the permutation, there are no problems with the other class.

The output of this code is 36 permutations, instead of 30. When reading the terminal, it is clear that there are duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `generator.nextPermutation()` twice instead of inserting `temp` into the array list

```
    while(generator.hasMorePermutations())
    {
        // get a permutation
        temp = generator.nextPermutation();
        // test for contains
        if(array.contains(temp))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // insert a new permutation instead of temp
            array.add(generator.nextPermutation());
            // print yet another new permutation instead of temp
            System.out.println(generator.nextPermutation());
            i++;
        }
```

Simply ensure you are doing `array.add(temp)` instead of `array.add(generator.nextPermutation())`

*Caveat: unless your permutation generator has a weird interface that only moves on to the next permutation when you call `hasMorePermutations`, in which case I have no idea why it isn't working!*

Comment: Actually you call `nextPermutation` three times, not twice, but as the `System.out.println` call is obviously for your debugging purposes I have more or less ignored that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your `nextPermutation()` three times instead of once. You should use `array.add(temp)` and `System.out.println(temp);` instead.